# LARK: All occurrences but the last one?

Tags: python, regex, lark-parser

Let say I have the following :

```
items : (item separator)+
```

this would work for :

```
i1, i2, i3,
```

but not for :

```
i1, i2, i3
```

how to make it so it does not require end-separator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like what you need:

```
items: item(,item)*
```